# Change timestamp depends on user's country in Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, timezone, cakephp-3.0

I want to change the timezone of the country so when a user delete an object, I can set the $timestamp from the user's country into a row related on that object.

I call a function into my controller like this:

```
 $turno = $this->Turnos->get($id);

    $countryid= $this -> Auth -> User()['countryid'];
$datos = getHoraDiaMesAnio($countryid);
    $fechaActual = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($datos[2]."-".$datos[1]."-".$datos[0]));
    $dia = $datos[0];   $mes = $datos[1];   $anio = $datos[2];
    $horaActual = date('H:i',strtotime($datos[4]));

    $hora = $datos[5];
    $timestamp = $anio."-".$mes."-".$dia." ".$hora;

    $turno->fechaBaja = $timestamp;
    //$turno->fechaBaja = $result;
    if ($this->Turnos->save($turno)) {
        $this->Flash->success(__('El turno se ha eliminado.'));
    } else {
        $this->Flash->error(__('El turno no se ha podido eliminar. Por favor intente de nuevo.'));
    }
    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
```

This is my function:

```
function getHoraDiaMesAnio($countyid){

    switch ($countyid){
        case 1://Argentina
            date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');
            putenv('TZ=America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');     
            break;
        case 2://Bolivia
            date_default_timezone_set('America/La_Paz');
            putenv('TZ=America/La_Paz');     
            break;
    $dia= date("j");
    $mes= date("m");
    $anio= date("Y");
    $horaRedondeada = date("H:00");
    $horaExacta = date("H:i");    
    $horaCompleta = date("H:i:s");

return array($dia,$mes,$anio,$horaRedondeada,$horaExacta,$horaCompleta);`
```

The problem is that the timestamp never sets correctly. In others services (without using cakephp) work perfectly. I think in cakephp I have to change in another way.

Could you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks unnecessarily complicated to me. I'd suggest to work with the date/time API provided by Cake/PHP instead, timezone adjustments should be a cake, and you can simply pass `\DateTimeInterface` objects into the saving process in case the column is of a date-time-ish type.

```
$now = \Cake\Chronos\Chronos::now(); // uses the default app timezone, see the
                                     // date_default_timezone_set() call in bootstrap.php

switch ($countryid) {
    case 1:
        $now = $now->setTimezone('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');   
        break;

    case 2:
        $now = $now->setTimezone('America/La_Paz');
        break;
}

$turno->fechaBaja = $now;
```

In case the `fechaBaja` column isn't of a date-time-ish type (it better be), simply format the object to a string:

```
$turno->fechaBaja = $now->toDateTimeString(); // formats as Y-m-d H:i:s
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Chronos](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/chronos.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Date & Time](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html)**
- **[PHP Manual > Date and Time](http://php.net/en/datetime)**

Comment: The solutions works, but the time is not the same time than in Argentina. I mean with:  $now = $now->setTimezone('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');   sets: 2017-06-04 11:44:51 when the realtime is 15:44:51

Comment: @FaustinoGagneten Works fine for me, I get `2017-06-04 16:11:28` right now... maybe your server time is not set correctly, or `setTimezone()` is not being invoked? What is `$now` being set to exactly before and after changing the timezone (try `debug($now)`)?

Comment: Result: 2017-06-04 19:31:03 Debug: 2017-06-04 19:31:03
2017-06-04 19:31:03 Debug: 2017-06-04 16:31:03. So it's ok the new datetime but in my database now is setting to 2017-06-04 11:44:51

Comment: edit: Result: 2017-06-04 19:31:03 Debug: 2017-06-04 19:31:03
2017-06-04 19:31:03 Debug: 2017-06-04 16:31:03. So it's ok the new datetime but in my database now is setting to 2017-06-04 12:31:03

Comment: Now if I do: debug($turno->fechaBaja) I get: 2017-06-04 16:44:12
 that is correct, but in my database I get 2017-06-04 12:44:12

Comment: The property fechaBaja in mysql database is a TIMESTAMP

Comment: @FaustinoGagneten That's what the `TIMESTAMP` type in MySQL does, it "_converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval_." **https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html** You should use `DATETIME` instead if you need to avoid this behavior.